# Кастомный словарь и врапер вокруг него

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, dict

У меня имеется немного модифицированный словарь и врапер для чтения json-файлов, наследующий сей словарь.

Проблема в том, что при записи в файл записывается и входящий аргумент врапера - `file`. Мне это ненужно. Что в данном случае мне следует сделать?

```
import collections
import functools
import json
import operator
import os


class Dict(dict):
    # TODO: add comp. function with "clone" feature
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.__dict__[key] = item

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.__dict__[key]

    def clear(self):
        return self.__dict__.clear()

    def copy(self):
        return self.__dict__.copy()

    def has_key(self, k):
        return k in self.__dict__

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__dict__.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def keys(self):
        return self.__dict__.keys()

    def values(self):
        return self.__dict__.values()

    def items(self):
        return self.__dict__.items()

    def pop(self, *args):
        return self.__dict__.pop(*args)

    def get(self, *args):
        return functools.reduce(operator.getitem, args, self.__dict__)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self.__dict__

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__dict__)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(repr(self.__dict__))
```

И сам врапер:

```
class Wrapper(Dict):
    def __init__(self, file):
        super(Wrapper, self).__init__()
        self.file = file
        with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as data:
            self.update(json.load(data))


    def __update(self, dicto, dictu):
        for k, v in dictu.items():
            if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
                dicto[k] = self.__update(dicto.get(k, {}), v)
            else:
                dicto[k] = v
        return dicto

    # save(<updated dict>) 
    def save(self, dict_, indent=4):
        u = self.__update(self.get(), dict_)
        with open(self.file, "wb") as file:
            data = json.dumps(u, indent=indent, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf8")
            file.write(data)
```

json-файл:

```
{
    "main": {
        "locale": "Русский"
    }
}
```

Вызов:

```
config = Wrapper(file="test.json")
config.save({"main": {"locale": "English"}})

print(config.get("main", "locale"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибут экземпляра `file`, как и остальные, содержится в словаре `__dict__`, поэтому он попадает в обновленный выходной файл. Чтобы этого избежать решений может быть много. Но, одно из самых универсальных (на случай, если класс-обертка будет расширяться другими атрибутами) - это механизм слотов.

Вам просто необходимо добавить нужные атрибуты в перечень слотов класса, чтобы исключить их из `__dict__`:

```
class Wrapper(Dict):
    __slots__ = "file"  # может быть кортежем из нужных атрибутов
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!